# Apache Camel with Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I can not find one (1) example project. It seems very strange to me.

I found intresting project from Red Hat.

[https://github.com/jboss-fuse/camel-spring-boot-examples/tree/main/spring-boot.](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/camel-spring-boot-examples/tree/main/spring-boot)

Last updated more than 2 years ago.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>3.16.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Extracted for Red Hat project. Error message saying cant find one.

No example project with Spring Boot 3 with Apache Camel. No one uses?

Apache Camel has

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Camel Starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... other dependencies ... -->
</dependencies>
```

I would like to have a look at an example project !! Not just code snippets. Please.

Answer (score 1):

All the examples in this [repo](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples) uses Spring Boot 3. For example you can check [this](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/tree/main/aot-basic) which shows how to use Spring Boot AOT with Apache Camel